# How to load object from pickle file without shadowing names from outer scope?

Tags: python, load, pickle, shadow

Pretty new to coding, sorry.

I'm writing a little text adventure, and attempting to add save/load functionality. I've included all my testing code I'm putting together for context. Hope it's not too much.

I have a series of nested functions to access the save and load functions. (In code: game>menu>choices 3,4). Saving and loading is giving me issues.

Error Messages:
For saving I'm getting an error: local variable 'cubicles' referenced before assignment.
For loading I'm getting an error: shadows name 'cubicles' from outer scope.

I suspect the issue is I'm creating a local variable within the nested function even though what I'm actually trying to do is alter a global. Is the proper way to fix this to simply write 'global' before the objects I'm loading?

Happy to take any other helpful criticism on the way I've written my code btw. Thanks.

(Edited Code for brevity - sorry I couldn't get it shorter.)

```
    import pickle

class Room:
    def __init__(self, state, name, desc):
        self.state = state
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc

    def enter(self):
        print("\n{}".format(self.name).upper())
        print(self.desc)
        print("Current room state: {}".format(self.state))


cubicles = Room(0, "your cubicle", "It's a room full of cubicles. You can go to Marcia's Office or your Boss's Office.")
marciaOffice = Room(0, "Marcia's office", "It's a small office where Marcia works. You can go to the cubicles or your Boss's Office.")
bossOffice = Room(0, "your Boss's office", "This is where your boss works. You can go to the cubicles or Marcia's Office.")
currentRoom = cubicles

print("You are in your cubicle")


def game():
    global currentRoom

    def decisionTree():

            print("What do you do?")
            response = input(">").lower()
            if ("advance" and "all") in response:
                advanceAll(response)
            elif ("menu" or "pause") in response:
                menu()
            else:
                print("Invalid response. Try going to another room or advancing the room state.")

    def advanceAll(response):
        if ("advance" and "all") in response:
            cubicles.state = 3
            marciaOffice.state = 7
            bossOffice.state = 9
            print("All rooms advanced to 3, 9, and 7.")
            game()

    def menu():
            print("MENU:")
            print("1. Return to Game")
            print("2. Quit")
            print("3. Save")
            print("4. Load")
            response = input(">")
            if "1" in response:
                game()
            elif "2" in response:
                quit()
            elif "3" in response:
                with open('save_game.pkl', 'wb') as save_game:
                    pickle.dump(cubicles, save_game)
                    pickle.dump(marciaOffice, save_game)
                    pickle.dump(bossOffice, save_game)
                    menu()
            elif "4" in response:
                with open('save_game.pkl', 'rb') as load_game:
                    cubicles = pickle.load(load_game)
                    marciaOffice = pickle.load(load_game)
                    bossOffice = pickle.load(load_game)
                    print("States are as follows:")
                    print("Cubicles:{}".format(cubicles.state))
                    print("Marcia's Office:{}".format(marciaOffice.state))
                    print("Boss's Office:{}".format(bossOffice.state))
                    menu()
            else:
                print("Unknown command")

    decisionTree()

game()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], not your whole program.

Comment: If your code returns an error, post the error message. `Include any error messages...` https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @martineau Sorry about that. I'm new, and it's showing. I reproduced it as briefly as I could.

Comment: @William I've added those error messages in. Sorry about that.

Comment: A [mre] would only need to have and example of saving some objects and then loading them back is a way that shadows names in the outer scope — whatever that means. No game code needed (or desired).